# Arbitrary state synthesis

Tags: quantum-state

I am confused with the term arbitrary state synthesis. Please refer the paper below:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176

They are giving gate counts for state synthesis. Do the state synthesis consume a fixed number of gates? I thought, the gates for the state synthesis depends on the application for which we are using quantum circuit. Please explain a little about arbitrary state synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the definition of quantum synthesis, there are some similarities to, and differences with, classical logical synthesis, for which there's a decent Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis).

In classical logic synthesis, given a Boolean function to which you wish to realize, and given a set of logic gates for which you can use, you are to create a Boolean circuit, using gates from this logical set and creating connections therebetween, that realize your specific function.

In quantum logic synthesis, one goal may be to create a circuit realizing a particular quantum *function* (e.g., a unitary function), that is built-up/synthesized from a particular set of simpler quantum gates.  For example you may create a quantum circuit to perform modular exponentiation for Shor's algorithm, or to perform the Quantum Fourier Transform, or do a Hamiltonian simulation of some physical system.  The gate counts may be a function of the complexity of the particular circuit.

Additionally although I haven't studied the linked paper of Shende, Bullock, and Markov, they do seem to emphasize another goal of quantum synthesis - you may be given a particular *initial state* (usually, but not always, the all-zero's ket $\vert 0\ldots0\rangle$), along with *target state*, and a set of allowed unitary gates.  You are to synthesize the target state, building a circuit with gates selected from the set of allowed gates, and connections therebetween, that go from the initial state to the target state.

For example one of the simplest states to prepare would be the uniform distribution over all initial inputs.  This is mostly straightforward - simply by performing a Hadamard gate on each of the supplied qubits.

The linked paper considers other algorithms for more complicated state synthesis, for example disentangling operations, wherein the initial state is not necessarily in some product state.

Comment: Thank you @Mark S for your answer.

Comment: Hi@Mark S, please provide me with a link of a  good paper related to the Arbitrary state synthesis.